# Show page total in all pages in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

i want to show page total in all pages which is called running total in crystal report.
the output will be like

```
Page 1

Employee Name         Salary
-------------         -------
keith                 2000
Robin                 4000
Mou                   3000

Sub Total             9000

Page 2

Employee Name         Salary
-------------         -------
Markc                 1000
Poll                  2500
Sam                   1500

Sub Total             5000
```

in this way sub total will come in all page. i am using table and tablix.
i got a trick from this site to show page total in all pages like

In SSRS 2008, you have the Tablix control. It defaults to a Header row and a Data row. Right-click on the data row, and select Insert Row -> Outside Group - Below. Then you have a footer row that you can add to the same way was in SSRS 2005.

the url is [SSRS adding a footer row to a table - CSV output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044219/ssrs-adding-a-footer-row-to-a-table-csv-output)

please have a look and give me right solution to achieve my output. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a found a solution for your problem, facing the same task (also adding a carry forward amount on the header of the page, so you can skip that part). I'm not grouping data here, but the technique is rather simple (no coding)

I created a blogpost on my website on it, explaining the details

http://www.tricks-and-tips.nl/tips-and-tricks/sql/ssrs-carry-forward-previous-page-and-running-totals-in-header-and-footer

Hope it can help you.

Peter